# ionic InAppBrowser request is unauthorized after closing the browser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am building an Ionic App for both iOS and Android in which I am using inappbrowser to login to my server,After gaining access into the server when i close the inappbrowser and make a request to the same server from the app the request seem to be authorized if I use iOS device but in Android the request seem to be unauthorized.

my code looks like this

```
let browser = this.iab.create("myserver.com/login/","_blank","{hardwareback:'no',hidenavigationbuttons:'yes',closebuttoncaption:'close'}");
browser.on('exit').subscribe(event=>{
 this.http.get("myserver.com/check_auth/",{},{}).then(res=>{
  console.log(res.data) // true on ios, false for android
 })
})
```

my backend is in Django.

Thanks in advance.